# Is annulus a compact surface? If so, what is homeomorphic to it?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Since it is bounded and closed, it seems so. Massey's text says that

Theorem 5.1 [Algebraic Topology An Introduction]
Any compact surface is homeomorphic to either a sphere or $n$-tori or the connected sum of $n$ projective planes.

But I cannot show annulus is homeomorphic to either one of them...

Answer (score 5):

Theorem 5.1 refers to surfaces without boundary. The annulus is a surface with boundary.